# Email authentication in Django ( strange error )

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have inserted this in settings.py:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'blog.auth.backends.EmailBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

blog is an application ( correctly installed ), auth is a folder in blog application, backends.py is the file that contain this method:

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from django.core.validators import email_re
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class EmailBackend(ModelBackend):

    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        if email_re.search(username):
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(email=username)
                if user.check_password(password):
                    return user
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                return None
        return None
```

My question is:

Why I get this error ? :

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /signup/
Error importing authentication backend auth.backends: "No module named auth.backends"
```

Comment: And __init__.py is there, in Blog folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make sure to have an `__init__.py` in all of the used folders (blog and auth)!

Answer (score 5):

Also you may need to clear your sessions 'delete from django_session;'.  I ran into that when upgrading django versions.

Comment: I even didn't realised that django auth backend module string could be cached! Spent more than 1h debugging it! And then simple session cleanup fixed it. Thanks.